# How to find the host name used to connect to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Our MySQL clients can use the IP DNS to connect to MySQL server. How can I find the actual host name used to connect to the server? Somehow I am interested in the connection string.

There is no way to find the host name or IP used to connect to the MySQL server also can be an answer!

Answer (score 1):

use the below query to get the hostname

```
select @@hostname
```

Comment: I shows the mysql host name, but the client can use the IP, the host name, or even the cname to connect to the server.